# Custom SharePoint app shows nothing

Tags: sharepoint

I created a SharePoint app using visual studio 2015 and added custom list within it.
When I deploy the application through SharePoint hosted, the deployment seems to be very successful without any errors but when I open it, it shows a page contains:
"Page Title" and "Hello [userName]"

Had anyone experienced such a problem..

Comment: It's just simple custom list, there is no code done. It shows something like this http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-RMG4RgHLoWs/VT5zwVsPIVI/AAAAAAAAA74/odrenO-DBIw/s1600/Capture6.PNG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see your custom list you have to make your url like this
http://'server url'/'app name'/Lists/'list name'

or in your App.js you can add the below mention code

var x = "'a href=" + _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/Lists/' My List" + "";
        $('#message').text('Hello ' + user.get_title());
        $('#message').append(x);

Please replace single quotes with brackets and with your actual value like server url, app name, list name.

Comment: Thanks @Rahul , it works very well
I appreciate that